# Bootstrap Popover on table row does not dismiss, even with 'trigger' set to 'focus'

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am trying to validate some table contents and display a popover next to a row whenever it contains an error.

The Popover is created dynamically and displayed with:

```
$('table#requests tbody tr')
.eq(1)  // highlight row #1
.popover({
    trigger: 'focus',
    placement: 'right',
    html: 'true',
    title: '<strong>Error!</strong>',
    content: 'This line does not make any sense. Click anywhere in the document to close this popover.',
    container: 'body',
})
.popover('show');
```

But then the popover cannot be dismissed with a click outside the element, es expected and documented in the Bootstrap documentation. I made sure to set `trigger`to `focus`and `container` to `body` to avoid side-effects with table-related elements.

I managed to reproduce the issue at https://jsfiddle.net/e31dcs4n/2/

Note that removing the `trigger` option allows clicking on the row to dismiss the popover (default behavior, because the popover is attached to the row). However, I want the user to be able to click **anywhere** to remove the popover.

Also note that calling `.focus()`, as detailed in [Bootstrap Popover Dismissable is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694669/bootstrap-popover-dismissable-is-not-working) does not help.

Comment: **[How about this workaround](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/e31dcs4n/3/)**?

Comment: Thanks @GuruprasadRao. Nice workaround indeed. Can you think of anything to make the `trigger` option work as expected though? If no one comes up with a better explanation in the next few hours, I will mark your answer as the correct one. I agree it does the job, though it might look like cheating :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your first question. You can add a click event to `body` wherein you can see whether the click happened outside the `body` and based on that you can `hide` the `popover`.

```
$('body').on('click', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).data('toggle') !== 'popover' && $(e.target).parents('.popover.in').length === 0) {
    $('.popover').popover('hide');
  }
});
```

**[Here's the DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/e31dcs4n/3/)**

---

I am not sure whether am answering your additional question specified in the comments, in a right way. But as per the **[post here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/twitter-bootstrap-stackoverflow/GHGwhkFDiVg)** popover doesn't work well with **tables**. I also tried workaround mentioned by him there, but it did not cope up well. The only thing works there is triggering `hover` of row, where in you don't need above hiding solution to be added.

```
$(function() {
  $('table#requests tbody tr:eq(1)').popover({
    placement: 'right',
    html: 'true',
    trigger: 'hover',
    title: '<strong>Error!</strong>',
    container: 'body',
    content: 'This line does not make any sense. Click anywhere in the document to close this popover.',
  })
});
```

**[Here's a DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/e31dcs4n/4/)** for above behaviour.

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)